# Using Windows failover cluster role TCP address for application

Tags: failovercluster

I have a 2 node Windows 2012 R2 guest failover cluster built as a generic service (say 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 are node 1 and node 2 static IP's).  The generic service role IP is 192.168.1.100.  the service communicates using a socket program.  I would like to force the outbound network traffic for this application out of the cluster generic service role (192.168.1.100).  Can this be done?